# Apple's JWT Identity token during the Sign In With Apple transfer period

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

I carefully checked the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/bringing_new_apps_and_users_into_your_team) and searched the net - but I didn't find the definitive answer. :(

After the transfer of the app from old dev team to new dev team is started, the Apple's user's auth response (JWT Identity token), will contain both `sub` and `transfer_sub` properties.

But what value will the `sub` property contain? Is it the **old** `sub` which was relevant for the old team, or it will contain **new** `sub` relevant for the new team?

I came across this 2 theories:

1. For the specific user, on the **first call** right after the migration
   started, the `sub` will contain old sub (related to old team), but on
   following calls it will contain the new sub (related to the new
   team)  *- or -*
2. From the start of the migration the sub will contain the new
   sub (related to new team) *- or -*
3. Something else?

(Of course - it is clear to me - that response will contain `transfer_sub` so we can match the user with user data in our db, also it is clear how to generate **new** sub based on `transfer_sub`.)

Thank you!

Comment: Giving minuses without any explanation - is really not helpful. It neither helps me with this question, and also it doesn't help me with asking better questions (assuming that something is wrong with this one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just received the answer from apple support:

> The `sub` (or user ID) is team-scoped.
>
> So, before the app transfer is complete, the user ID returned will be associated with the app
> owner—the transferring team.
>
> Upon completion of the app transfer, the user ID returned will still be associated with the app owner—
> the recipient team.
>
> This unique value will be different for each team, but the `transfer_sub` (or transfer ID) will remain the same
> across the developer team pairs.

**UPDATE**: Please note that "*Upon completion of the app transfer*" doesn't refer to the end of 60 days transition period, but to the period of few min to few days which are needed for the app to appear on the target team account.